# SharpDX: Content Assets not found

Tags: c#, directx, sharpdx

what could be the problem if my assets are not found when using the sharpdx toolkit contentpipeline.

```
sf = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("Arial16ClearType");
```

they are in a subdirectory called "Content" and it is set in the application:

```
Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
```

the buildaction is set correctly to Toolkitfont. 
"Copy to output directory" is "do not copy".

i imported the buildactions by adding this to my csproj

```
<Import Project="f:\work\github\SharpDX\SharpDX.targets" />
```

and it is always throwing this exception

```
SharpDX.Toolkit.Content.AssetNotFoundException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Content\Arial16ClearType
  Source=SharpDX.Toolkit
  StackTrace:
       at SharpDX.Toolkit.Content.ContentManager.FindStream(String assetName) in ..\..\Source\Toolkit\SharpDX.Toolkit\Content\ContentManager.cs:line 330
       at SharpDX.Toolkit.Content.ContentManager.Load(Type assetType, String assetName, Object options) in ..\..\Source\Toolkit\SharpDX.Toolkit\Content\ContentManager.cs:line 201
       at SharpDX.Toolkit.Content.ContentManager.Load[T](String assetName, Object options) in ..\..\Source\Toolkit\SharpDX.Toolkit\Content\ContentManager.cs:line 163
       at glyphrenderer.GlyphGame.LoadContent() in GlyphGame.cs:line 78
       at SharpDX.Toolkit.Game.InitializeBeforeRun() in ..\..\Source\Toolkit\SharpDX.Toolkit.Game\Game.cs:line 326
       at SharpDX.Toolkit.GameWindowDesktop.RunRenderLoop() in ..\..\Source\Toolkit\SharpDX.Toolkit.Game\Desktop\GameWindowDesktop.cs:line 340
       at SharpDX.Toolkit.GameWindowDesktop.Run() in ..\..\Source\Toolkit\SharpDX.Toolkit.Game\Desktop\GameWindowDesktop.cs:line 302
       at SharpDX.Toolkit.GamePlatform.Run(GameContext gameContext) in ..\..\Source\Toolkit\SharpDX.Toolkit.Game\GamePlatform.cs:line 133
       at SharpDX.Toolkit.Game.Run(GameContext gameContext) in ..\..\Source\Toolkit\SharpDX.Toolkit.Game\Game.cs:line 378
       at glyphrenderer.Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you meant by "the buildaction is set correctly" but you have to use the build action `ToolkitFont` and not `Content` and without specifying "Copy to output directory", as it is done by the `ToolkitFont` task. Check the projects in Toolkit samples that are configured this way. The Toolkit tasks are responsible to compile the xml/source files into a binary form that will be loaded at runtime.

Comment: thanks for the reply. actually that is exactly what i have, Build Action is set to ToolkitFont and they are not copied to output directory. a slight difference i noticed, that in the samples solution the assets have a little blue overlay above the icon and they dont have that in my solution.

Comment: Can you check in the `Content` directory in the bin directory of your exe, if the file `Arial16ClearType.tkb` is there? Also when you fully compile your project, you should see a build output like `Compilation successful of C:\Code\SharpDX\Samples\Toolkit\Desktop\SpriteBatchAndFont\..\..\Common\SpriteBatchAndFont\Content\Arial16.xml to C:\Code\SharpDX\Samples\Toolkit\Desktop\SpriteBatchAndFont\obj\Debug\Content\Arial16.tkb`